# How to use an npm module in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, module, npm

I've been trying to use a `npm` module called `solc` in `AngularJs` but I can't seem to succeed in anyway.

I know it's meant to be used with a `Node` application but I was wondering if there is a way to use it client side.

I've been trying to use `Require.js` and require every file included inside the `git-repo` but there are too many dependencies so I was wondering if there is another way.

I've been looking at browserify but that doesn't seems to do exactly what I need.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `npm` package in browser applications if the package does not have any dependency on Node's built-in APIs. That's because Node APIs are available on server side and not on browser.

If you see [here](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js/blob/master/solcjs#L4) and [here](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js/blob/master/wrapper.js#L2) in the github repo of `solc`, you will see that it requires Node's built-in modules `path` and `https`. So it will not work in any browser application.